# Amazon Data Pipeline: When does ShellCommandActivity start the On Fail Action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

How does the AWS Pipeline determine if a ShellCommandActivity fails or not and when it starts the corresponding on Fail action? Can I write code in the script which checks if the actions where done correctly and then "tells" the AWS Pipeline that the Activity was sucessfull or not?

Answer (score 2):

onFailAction for ShellCommandActivity is triggered when the ShellCommand returns a non-zero exit code.